# how to set xdebug.max_nesting_level=200 while installing magento

Tags: php, magento

> Your current setting of xdebug.max_nesting_level=100. Magento 2 requires it to be >set to 200 or more. Edit your config, restart web server, and try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add below line in php.ini file

xdebug.max_nesting_level = 200